# keyboard to change desktop in terminal server client

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services

I'm using tsclient 0.150, running on ubuntu,m to access a windows remote computer

with ctrl-alt-enter I can exit and enter full-screen mode

I'd like to be able to use ctrl-alt-left and ctrl-alt-right to be able to switch desktops

may be some rdesktop configuration file some where around to tell tsclient which key combination to send to the remote machine and which ones to send to the local box. I've tried with "Enable window manager's key binding" but it redirects every key to the local machine.

right now I have to ctrl-alt-enter and then click with the mouse in the window title...

thanks a lot

--

ps: I had a look at http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop and couldn't find anything useful...